# Twitter API 1.1 oauth give me a bad authentification data with Phonegap

Tags: twitter, cordova, twitter-oauth

After Oauth authentification done with Oauth.io, i can't have access to the user_timeline, it only show a bad authentification data with the code 215. Maybe i forgot some parameters or my connexion is wrong ? I did'nt find any issue to my problem. I think i'm missing something but i can't find what. 
I paste my code below, if someone could help me :)

Thanks

```
$(document).on( 'deviceready', function() {



 OAuth.initialize("my key");

    $('#twitter-connect').on('click', function() {

    OAuth.popup('twitter', function(error, result) {

    result.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json').done(function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    var screen_name = data.screen_name;

    $.ajax({ 
    url : "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", 
    dataType: "json", 
    type: "get", 
    data:{ 
    screen_name: screen_name 
    },

    error: function(xhr, status){ 
    alert(xhr.responseText); 
    },

    success: function(data, xhr, status){ 
    console.log(data); 
    } 
    }); 
    }); 
    }); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used jQuery.ajax instead of the `result` of OAuth.popup() to make the API call. Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCZu3/1/

You can do it this way:

```
$(document).on( 'deviceready', function() {
   OAuth.initialize("my key")
   $('#twitter-connect').on('click', function() {
      OAuth.popup('twitter', function(error, result) {
         result.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json').done(function(data) {
            console.log(data)

            var screen_name = data.screen_name

            result.get({
               url: '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
               data: {
                  screen_name: screen_name
               }
            }).done(function(timeline) {
               console.log(timeline)
            }).error(function(error) {
               console.log(error)
            })
         })
      })
   })
})
```